# How to prevent Pandas from trying to create S3 bucket when uploading CSV file

Tags: pandas, csv, amazon-s3

If I try to upload a CSV file using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.to_csv("s3://super_dumb_s3_bucket/not_real.csv")
```

and the `super_dumb_s3_bucket` bucket doesn't exists yet (or I don't have access to it) I'm getting the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CreateBucket operation: Access Denied
```

how can I change it so it will fail without trying to create a bucket? if the user running the code will have permissions for this action I will have "zombie" bucket every-time someone has a typo.

Comment: You need to check your Iam role of the AWS account and provide access for S3.

Comment: access to what resources? I don't want my users to be able to create buckets in S3. I want to protect myself that even if I gave them permission to create bucket it will create one when trying to upload file to S3.

Comment: AWS configuration part is done for accessing AWS cli?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding what / why are you asking. I know how to allow / block users to create bucket in S3, but this is NOT what I want to do, I want to PREVENT pandas from trying to create the bucket if it doesn't exist yet. make sense?